# Flutter close alert dialog without popping the screen

Tags: flutter

```dart
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, false);
},
```

I have use `navigator.pop` but it closes the screen, also not just the alert dialog. Is it possible to just close the dialog without closing the current screen?

Comment: `Navigator.of(context).pop()`

Comment: I have also tried that one but its the same result

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong which I can not tell with the code you have provided in your question

Comment: more likely you are not sending right context into your alert dialog